# Even distribution of buttons (various widths) along nav bar

Tags: html, css, navigation

I have a basic navigation bar of 7 items:

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Company</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Management</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Development Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Newsroom</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

The idea is for the buttons to be evenly distributed across the navigation bar, with the first button flushed to the left margin and the right button flushed to the right margin. I don't just want to center the navigation bar, because I need the first and last buttons to stick to those margins.

The only way I know of spreading buttons is by adding margin-right to every one but the last one. The problem is that, if I do this I can get quite close to having the last button reach the right margin, but only quite.

I read a solution where buttons had equal % widths (example, 4 buttons each with a width of 25%), but in my case I have long buttons and short ones and I want the spaces between the buttons to remain constant. How could I make it so that they distribute automatically?

This is the css I'm using right now (the nav bar is 836 pixels wide and all buttons have a separation of 16px between them):

```
header nav{
padding: 12px 62px;
width:836px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}

header nav ul {
list-style-type: none;
}

header nav ul li{
display: inline-block;
}

header nav ul li a{
margin-right:16px;
}

header nav ul li:last-child a{
margin-right:0px;
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **:first-of-type** and **:last-of-type**  to float the first and last Li's to the desired positions, then share the remaining space between the rest of the LI's.

```css
* {
  margin: 0 auto!important;
}

ul {
  text-align: center; /* Distribute the none floated LI'S evenly */
  width: 650px;
  padding: 0;
}

ul li {
  display: inline;
  padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
  margin: 0;
}

ul li:first-of-type { /* Refers to the first Li */
  float: left;
  padding-left: 0;
}

ul li:last-of-type { /* Refers to the last Li */
  float: right;
  padding-right: 0;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Company</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Management</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Projects</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Development Services</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Newsroom</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Contact</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think I actually understand what you mean, but if I did this is my solution:

use this as your CSS file:

```
header nav{
padding: 12px 62px;
width:836px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}

header nav ul {
list-style-type: none;
}

header nav ul li{
display: inline-block;
}

header nav ul li a{
margin-right:16px;
}

header nav ul li:last-child a{
margin-right:0px;
}

ul li {
display: inline;
}
```